# Nested JSON with Django apiREST

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST Framework view like this:

```
#views.py
class RegistroViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Registro.objects.all()
serializer_class = RegistroSerializer
```

and JSON response has this format

```
[{"id": 1 .....}]
```

and i need something like this

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"id":"1" ...}]}
```

and the serializer

```
class RegistroSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
idProce = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False)
idEntidad = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False)
idUsuario =  serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False)

class Meta:

    model = Registro
```

What should i do?(Django newbie)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelViewSet is a very polished class that makes one thing very good: return serialized models, and that's about it. In this case you could create your own ViewSet to take care of that model for you, it would let you choose the way you show your data, it would look something like this:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class RegistroViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet): #just ViewSet, not ModelViewSet
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Registro.objects.all()
        serializer = RegistroSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        my_dict = {'success': True, 'data':serializer.data}
        return Response(my_dict)
```

Comment: i have this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items' ,my serializers model has this form-  class registroSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer): ... should i change that too?

Comment: It's not a problem with your serializer class, but I also don't see any problem with the code in my answer. Can you give me a full stack trace?

Comment: Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  69.             for method, action in actions.items():

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/registros/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: If you're not registering your view with a Router, you may need to map the ViewSet actions manually in your urlconf: `url(r'^/api/registros/', RegistroViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}))`

Comment: that returns 404, but i solved it change this -  class RegistroViewSet(APIView) , but return this {"data": [{"id" ... }] , "success": true}, why? .

Comment: dictionaries in python have no notion of order of keys, so the JSON renderer should assume any order. Is the order of the keys critical to your implementation?

Comment: i'm not sure, so can i change that order?

Comment: if there's no explicit need, you shouldn't. The JSON format doesn't enforce an specific order in the keys. If it's for something aesthetical, you're welcome to try and implement your own JSONRenderer that supports OrderedDict, but I wouldn't advise it...